# Silverlight 4 to Silverlight 5 migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am starting to upgrade my Silverlight projects from SL4 to SL5, is there any key points/best practices to keep in mind?

Any specific issues with Visual studio 2010 + Silverlight 5?

Comment: Manu Please accept it as an answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly it does not differ a lot

Heres the msdn migration link

[Silverlight 4-5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh397894%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)